# What is the right awk regex to match folder, hidden folder, normal file, so I can colorize them using escape code, and where to put the syntax

Tags: regex, awk, colors, ls

```
ls -lhAXF --group-directories-first "$@" | awk '
    BEGIN {
        FPAT = "([[:space:]]*[^[:space:]]+)";
    } {
        $1 = "\033[1m" "\033[31m" $1 "\033[0m";
        $2 = "\033[1m" "\033[32m" $2 "\033[0m";
        $3 = "\033[1m" "\033[33m" $3 "\033[0m";
        $4 = "\033[34m" $4 "\033[0m";
        $5 = "\033[1m" "\033[35m" $5 "\033[0m";
        $6 = "\033[1m" "\033[36m" $6 "\033[0m";
        $7 = "\033[1m" "\033[37m" $7 "\033[0m";
        $8 = "\033[1m" "\033[33m" $8 "\033[0m";
        print
    }'
```

[link to the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTUzz.png)

what is the correct syntax to achieve the following:

1. color normal directory to red
2. color hidden directory to blue
3. color regular file to green

what i know:

1. match normal directory with regex like any word ending with '/' inside column $9
2. match hidden directory with regex like any word starting with '.' inside column $9
3. match regular file with regex like the rest of line that doesn't match ending with '/' and doesn't match starting with '.'
4. i know something like: `awk '$9 ~ /something/'` to match the right column

but where to put the syntax, and what is the syntax look like?

i want to colorize the result of the regex after it matches using escape code like "\033[32m"

Comment: Your question is not clear. You write that you want to "_colour normal directory to red_" but you show an awk script and an image where it is the various columns that are coloured, note the lines. So, for "_normal directories_", for instance, what information do you want to be printed in red? Its name? The permissions? Other? And what about the other colours?

Comment: i mean it's name, other thing like the permission is already coloured

Comment: Parsing the output of `ls` is a well known anti-pattern, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, so that's a bad starting point for your script.

Comment: You're asking how to "color normal directory to red" but of course awk has no idea what string(s) in the input indicate a "directory", never mind a "normal directory". If you want help writing an awk script to parse some input then you need to provide a [mcve] with sample input and expected output. Don't assume that we know which string in the output of some command (e.g. `ls`) represents a "normal directory" - show the input to awk and tell us which strings in that input mean "normal directory". Also add the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments parsing the output of `ls` is not recommended; `ls` is for humans only. But if you absolutely want to do it this way you can try the following:

```
ls -lhAXF --group-directories-first "$@" | awk '
  BEGIN {FPAT = "([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*)"}
  {if($1 ~ /^d/ && $9 ~ /^\./) $9 = "\033[31m" $9
   else if($1 ~ /^d/) $9 = "\033[32m" $9
   else $9 = "\033[33m" $9
   for(i=1;i<NF;i++) $i = sprintf("\033[3%dm%s", i, $i)
   $1 = "\033[1m" $1
   $NF = $NF "\033[0m"
   print}'
```

We first redefine the fields as word-spaces instead of spaces-word because it makes the detection of hidden directories, non-hidden directories and non-directories easier: the relevant parts are now at the beginning of the field:

- `$1 ~ /^d/` => directory
- `$9 ~ /^\./` => hidden

We also simplify a bit by suppressing useless intermediate ANSI codes and by using a for loop to prepend the ANSI colour code to each field.

The rest is straightforward. We first prepend the colour ANSI escape codes to `$9` (name field) based on the type. Next, we prepend the colour ANSI escape codes to the other fields, based on the field index. Finally, we prepend the bold code to `$1` and append the reset code to the last field, and we print.

---

Edit by Ed Morton: here is the above script pretty-printed by `gawk -o-` for improved legibility:

```
BEGIN {
        FPAT = "([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*)"
}

{
        if ($1 ~ /^d/ && $9 ~ /^\./) {
                $9 = "\033[31m" $9
        } else if ($1 ~ /^d/) {
                $9 = "\033[32m" $9
        } else {
                $9 = "\033[33m" $9
        }
        for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) {
                $i = sprintf("\033[3%dm%s", i, $i)
        }
        $1 = "\033[1m" $1
        $NF = $NF "\033[0m"
        print
}
```

Comment: Hope you don't mind but I couldn't make head nor tail of your script as formatted so I had to pretty-print it with gawk for me to be able to understand it and so I edited your answer to add that output as it may help the OP and others too.

Comment: Thanks guys, i'm still new to the world of linux and scripting, this works. I'll try to figure out how to use find instead of ls. I do this because i want the ls to look beautiful instead of installing other alternative to ls like "lsd" "exa", etc

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to test for the trailing slashes applied to directory names by `ls -F`.

What you are looking for is something like this:

```
BEGIN {
    red = "\033[31m" # dir
    green = "\033[32m" # file
    blue = "\033[36m" # hidden dir
    reset = "\033[0m"
}

{
    if ($9 ~ /\/$/) {
        if ($9 ~ /^\./) {
            $9 = blue $9 reset
        }
        else {
            $9 = red $9 reset
        }
    }
    else {
        $9 = green $9 reset
    }
}
```

But **it breaks if file names contain spaces/tabs**.

You could test the first character of column 1 (of `ls -l`) instead (`d` or `-`)… But you’d be better off looking in to utilities like `stat` and `find`.